# Overlaying the page contents from Google Chrome extension

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome-extension

I am writing a very simple Google Chrome extension, but have faced such a multitude of issues that it's a bit overwhelming for a project of such a miserable scale.

The extension is a very simple one: upon arrival on any page (say, google.com) the page contents is hidden and the user is faced with a question (s)he has to answer correctly... or be redirected to some other page that provides the correct answer. In other words, the user cannot access pages on the Internet unless (s)he answers the questions correctly.

To hide the page contents I decided to go for a simple overlay using the following approaches:

## Approach #1

I tried appending to the current document's body a simple opaque `div` with `position: fixed;`, `z-index: 2147483647;` and width/height at 100%. That worked, but:

- The page's CSS kept interfering with the elements inside of my `div`.
- Flash content occasionally appeared on top of it (at least on Windows XP).
  Chasing `embed`s all over the page and setting `wmode` to
  "transparent" didn't help, offsetting to -10000px or setting
  `display:none;` simply alleviated but didn't solve the problem. See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10372906/chrome-extension-jstree-iframe-drag-and-drop).

## Approach #2

I tried sandboxing the GUI in an `iframe` that is created and injected into the page to behave exactly as the `div` in the above approach. It perfectly solves the issues of the first approach, but:

- Apparently there's no way to access the contents of the `iframe` because of cross-origin policy. And that access – I need it to assign handlers to the input field where the user is typing the answer, I need to remember who's stealing the focus from my answer input field to give it back once the question is answered, etc. etc. etc.
- Using [Message Passing](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging.html) didn't work for me and *I'm not even sure if I should* make it work because messaging makes the entire thing overly complex and prohibits me from using the application as a simple webpage (i.e. not as an extension). Why even bother?

So... where am I wrong with my approaches? Is there a third or a fourth one that I'm not aware of?

I appreciate but don't really need code as an answer. A hint or a push to the right direction would be just as good.

P.S. I suppose that at some point somebody will ask if I have code to share. I do, but there's a bunch of it. Which part specifically would you like to see?

Comment: How about a nuclear option? Use your content script to blast away the entire DOM of the called page. Then replace the DOM with your own code. Once the question is answered redirect the user to the target (but don't blow it up this time).

Comment: @mrtsherman I've thought of a nuke-it-from-orbit solution, but that could result in a horrible radioactive fallout when *paying for stuff* on the Internet. You know, the online payment systems where you shouldn't really hit the "back" button.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Totally forgot about this question... In the end I went with approach 2 using message passing to communicate with the iframe and it works pretty fine. Here's a repo of the extension for those who are interested in reading the code: https://github.com/olegskl/invasive-kanji

Answer (score 5):

## Approach #2

#### Concern #1

> Apparently there's no way to access the contents of the iframe because
>   of cross-origin policy. And that access – I need it to assign handlers
>   to the input field where the user is typing the answer, I need to
>   remember who's stealing the focus from my answer input field to give
>   it back once the question is answered, etc. etc. etc

Yes you access contents of iframe(s) for matter all the code of a Web Page, no CSP etc.

## Content script injecting an iframe.

I suggest this is best approach , you can inject script to dynamic generated iframes as shown here and fetch content

### Sample Implementation

#### manifest.json

```
{
    "name": "Iframe",
    "description": "",
    "version": "1",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "content_scripts": [
        {
            "matches": [
                "<all_urls>"
            ],
            "js": [
                "myscript.js"
            ],
            "run_at": "document_end"
        },
        {
            "matches": [
                "<all_urls>"
            ],
            "js": [
                "anotherscript.js"
            ],
            "all_frames": true
        }
    ],
    "permissions": [
        "<all_urls>"
    ]
}
```

#### myscript.js

```
var iframe = document.createElement("iframe");
iframe.setAttribute("src", "https://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=http://allofrgb.blogspot.in/");
iframe.setAttribute("style", "border:none; width:150px; height:30px");
iframe.setAttribute("scrolling", "no");
iframe.setAttribute("frameborder", "0");
document.body.appendChild(iframe);
```

#### anotherscript.js

```
iframes = document.getElementsByTagName("iframe");
for (iframe in iframes){
    console.log(iframes[iframe].src);
}
console.log("In another Script");
```

If you observe console logged messages you observe messages are logged twice (`document` log + `iframe` log + `[any number of optional iframes in pages]*`)

`anotherscript.js` which runs during `document idle` states does execute in dynamic generated iframe, how ever you can re-run content script through [chrome.tabs.executeScript()](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs.html#method-executeScript) any time.

#### Concern #2

> Using Message Passing didn't work for me and I'm not even sure if I
>   should make it work because messaging makes the entire thing overly
>   complex and prohibits me from using the application as a simple
>   webpage (i.e. not as an extension). Why even bother?

What is you want to achieve?

Comment: Well, `iframeElement.src` is indeed a publicly available read/write property. But try calling a `getElementById` on that iframe to get some element that's *inside the iframe* and you'll get an "Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame..." error.

Comment: Also, I do understand *what* Message Passing is all about, but I'd rather use it only as a last resort.

Comment: You avoid the error by not accessing anything within the `iframe`.